# Angle between a normal vector and angle of observation

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

If one is looking down a camera at a [conical frustum](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2013/Kar/EMAT%206690/Essay%202/Frustum.pdf#:%7E:text=Conical%20Frustum%20is%20a%20Frustum%20created%20by%20slicing,base%20as%20pictured%20below%3A%20The%20Volume%20of%20Frustum%3A?msclkid=bd4901fdc01b11ec95b72d94bb0a9770) (by that I mean a cone with the top sliced off with the cut parallel to base) such that the side of the frustrum has a certain angle with respect to the z-axis, what is the angle between a normal vector to this surface and the line going through the camera?

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding the setup of this problem. What "line going through the camera"? The side of the frustrum has many normals, depending on where on the surface you are looking at. Could you provide a picture? What are the quantities that you know?

Comment: Perhaps I am not explaining properly.  Say the bottom base of the frustum sits on the $xy$-plane and then the line of observation is just along the $y$-axis towards the frustum.  What is the angle between the $y$-axis and the normal to the surface which sits in the $xz$-plane?  I know the diameters of the bottom and top circles and the height of the frustrum, so can determine the angle which the edge of the frustum makes to the $z$-axis.

Comment: You are not specifying enough information. Suppose that the bases are centered on the $z$ axis, so that the bottom is at $(0,0,0)$ and the top is at $(0,0,h)$. The intersection of the frustum and the $xz$ plane is a trapeze. If you take any normal to the side surface at a point on this trapeze, then the normal will be in the $xz$ plane. If your direction of observation is along $y$, then the angle is $90^\circ$. If you look at a point on the surface at $y\ne 0$, then the angle depends on $x$ (or $z$).